# When I add in a <p> tag, it pushes down the <div> next to it onto the next line. How can I keep everything on the same line?

Tags: html, css, centering

I'm creating an online store and i'm trying to edit the code to add some custom features.

My site is www.comfykitty.co

[image: Screenshot]

I'm trying to add "More Styles Available" centered in the line below the title (of certain products such as "Fruit Print Bed"). I have my price float: left; and sale tag float: right;

I've been trying for hours to get it to be centered but it either goes onto another line or stays left and goes under the price `<div>`.

I think I've added the relevant CSS and HTML code that shows what I've done. Please help me center the `<p></p>` on the same line with the price and sale tag. I've removed the HTML and if statements and other irrelevant code that does other things that wouldn't have been in the tags (that's why there's nothing in the tags).

```css
.pricearea {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 5px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #d1b3ff;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue;
}

.saletag_area {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="pricearea">
  //Code for displaying price would've been here
  <p style="color: red; display: inline;">Other Styles Available</p>


  <div class="saletag_area" style="display: inline;">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Have you try flex-box? if you not, I recommend you check it out.

Comment: Do you want to center 'Other styles available' inrelation to the priceArea? When just apply display:block and text-align:center to p element. Price and saletagArea should be float as they are now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `float` and then give each div an equal `width`:

```css
.pricearea {
  /* position: absolute; */
  padding-left: 5px;
  /* width: 60px; */
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #d1b3ff;
  font-weight: bold;
  /* float: left; */
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue;
}

.pricearea>div {
  float: left;
  width: 33.3333%;
}

.text-left {
  text-align: left;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.text-right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="pricearea">
  <div class="text-left">$10</div>
  <div class="text-center">Other Styles Available</div>
  <div class="text-right saletag_area" style="display: inline;">save</div>
</div>
```